# Object added to []interface{}. Now need to fetch the object and call the Object’s respective Display() fn

Tags: function, go, interface

I have done the following:

- Defined a "Parent" interface with Display() fn.
- Created 2 Child structs which implement their respective Display() fn.
- In main(), created 2 child objects and added them to : `availableObjs[]interface{}`
- Now, in For loop, want to take the object and call its respective Display() function. This is where I am struck at.

**GoPlayground Code :** https://play.golang.org/p/jdHpueokrEk

Tried searching online.

**Same Code inline :**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

////// Parent Interface which has Display() fn.
type Parent interface {
    Display()
}

// 2 Child structs implementing their Display() fn.
type Child1 struct {
    name1 string
}

type Child2 struct {
    name2 string
}

func (c1 Child1) Display() {
    fmt.Println("c1Name : ", c1.name1)
}

func (c2 Child2) Display() {
    fmt.Println("c2Name : ", c2.name2)
}
////////////////////////////////////////////

// Maintains the created objects
var availableObjs []interface{}

func main() {
    //// Creating 2 objects
    c1 := Child1{"Child1"}
    c2 := Child2{"Child2"}

    // Adding 2 objects to availableObjs
    availableObjs = append(availableObjs, c1)
    availableObjs = append(availableObjs, c2)

    // Now, want to fetch the Object from Interface and call its respective Display() fn.
    for _, obj := range availableObjs {
            fmt.Println("")
        fmt.Println("Obj Got = ",obj)
        fmt.Println("Obj type = ",reflect.TypeOf(obj))
        //obj.Display()        //  <-- Problem Line 
    }
}
```

**Need to do :** Need inputs on how I can call Display() function after getting object from array interface.

Comment: Use type assertion, or instead of `[]interface{}` define your slice as `[]Parent`.

Comment: Not sure if the names are just random but remember that interfaces and concrete types *do not have* a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Stop trying to mimic inheritance. There is NO inheritance in Go and literally _any_ attempt to fake it will lead to disaster. Do not even try! You will fail!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this: one is by instead of using the empty interface you use the proper Parent interface to declare the slice:

```golang
// Maintains the created objects
var availableObjs []Parent
```

Please note that the naming of `Parent` for your interface suggests that you are approaching interfaces with the concept of inheritance, which is not something we use in Go. You must think of interfaces more like a behaviour. In this particular case, you want to represent the behaviour of something capable of "displaying", so you may well call the interface `Displayer`.

This naming convention, appending `-er` to the interface name, is a very common pattern in Go, even though sometimes you get some strange names :)

In the same sense, the `Child` structs are not actually children of the Parent interface, they are just structs that implicitly satisfy the interface.

They could satisfy any number of interfaces at the same time. For instance, if they had a String() method they would also satisfy the `fmt.Stringer` interface.

Now, the second option is to use a type assertion, either with a switch statement or a type statement:

```golang
switch t := obj.(type) {
case Parent:
    t.Display() // note that 't' is the new typed variable
}
```

Or

```
t, ok := obj.(Parent)
if ok {
    t.Display()
}
```

Please note that the `ok` variable above can be omitted, but in that case the code will panic if the type assertion doesn't match.